# Popper js add animation to action menu

Tags: javascript, css, animation, css-animations

I am using popper js to create an action menu.

```
this.popper = new Popper(originElement, dropdownElement,  {,
      removeOnDestroy: true,
      modifiers: {
        applyStyle: {
          onLoad: () => {
            dropdownElement.style.display = "block";
          }
        }
      }
    });
```

My problem is that it just shows the dropdown without animation. I can't find anything in the docs about animation. How can I add animation?

Comment: Looks like popper.js has no native animation support. May be you can go with css animation instead?

Answer (score 2):

The reason why there is no "animation" is that you transition from `display: none;` to `display: block`.

There is no way to animate the change between these two states, but there are different ways to approach this problem. You could for instance animate `opacity: 0` to `opacity: 1` which would make the dropdown fade in / fade out.

My personal favourite is animating max-height. To do this: Set your menu's CSS like this:

```
.yourclassname {
   max-height:0;
   overflow:hidden; /* Like this your content will not be visible until the height is high enough */
   transition: max-height ease .5s; /* Animation */
}
```

In JS all you need to do is set the max height to something like 1000px or less/more and your animation is done.